# Adding feature layers in Esri's WebAppBuilder without using Add Data widget

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-web-appbuilder

I've added a feature layer to the "my content" section but the only way I can seem to add it to the WebAppBuilder is through the AddData widget.  When I try adding it through the "Attribute -> Extra Data Source" then it inds the feature layer, but nothing displays on the map.  Then, in a custom widget I'm trying to create, I tried to use the Javascript API to add the feature layer to the map object.  It doesn't throw any errors, it just doesn't display the layer.

Any ideas? I'm not sure why the AddData widget would be different from the other methods, I tried looking through the code but didn't find anything that jumped out at me.  Maybe I'm just missing something small?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, layers are added to the Web Map and the Web Map is set in the application.

The Add Data widget is used to allow end users of your application the ability to add their own data sources.

Build up a web map with all the operational layers. Save the map. Set this web map inside Web AppBuilder. Configure widgets to make use of the layers. Save and launch the app.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks! I'll try that out